How to Generate Detailed Logs for All Requests in Locust Stress Testing?
I'm using Locust for stress testing my application API, and I need to generate detailed logs for all HTTPS requests sent during the test. Specifically, I want to capture the following details for each request:
Request URL
HTTP method
Response status code
Request payload (if any)
Response body
Timestamp of the request
Whether the request was received successfully by the server or not

The purpose of this log is to analyze which requests were received and processed by the server and to troubleshoot any issues with requests that were not handled correctly. I want the log to be in CSV file

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Locust can generate CSV files using the --csv parameter, but it doesnt give you per-request info.
If you need individual request data, consider Locust Dashboards or locust.cloud
Or just write your own request event handler that logs every request.
